# rospy tf get frame_id of trans, rot

Tags: rospy, ros-kinetic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

Assume I have three tf's:

1): marker_1 relative to world

2): marker_2 relative to world

3):  marker_3 relative to world

Now I want to get the marker name that is closest to marker_1. Is there a direct function in rospy to get this or do I have to iterate over all frame_id of the tf and thereby find it out?

Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317872/rospy-tf-get-frame_id-of--trans,-rot/) by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2019-03-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-03-07**:
To the best of my knowledge you'll have to make this function yourself. This is not the primary purpose of the TF system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Pete's comment should have been an answer, so just to take this out of the Unanswered queue: No, you'll have to iterate through them and check the distances yourself.

Note that you *can* use the tf2 (and tf) data types to calculate the distance and save yourself a little bit of conversion trouble. See [here](http://docs.ros.org/api/tf2/html/namespacetf2.html#a5e281b338495703f8971d29da084570b).

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2019-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1